# unsupported media type for an android rest client

Tags: android, rest, types, media

I try to send a request from android emulator to a restful server. But I always get the Error:

> 415 Unsupported Media Type.

The code of client:

```
public JSONtest() throws Exception, IOException{

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(AppServerIP);
    JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
    param.put("name", "weiping");
    param.put("password", "123456");
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(param.toString());
    request.setEntity(se);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(request);
    String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
    System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
}
```

The code of the server:

```
public class resource {
    @POST
    @Path("/trigger")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response trigger(JSONObject notify) throws Exception{            
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("134124").tag("213q").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();       
}
```

Comment: Ha, this is sooo exactly the problem I was facing! Thanks alot

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that the server doesn't know the media type of the client's request.
Try something like this in the client code:

`request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");`